# PHP Regex for replacing comma and newlines within apostrophe

Tags: php, regex

I need to write a regular expression that looks for a string within an apostrophe and replaces newlines and commas with spaces. Im not skilled at regular expression. Can someone assist? I believe Id be using the preg_replace function.

Thanks

Comment: I havent tried anything. I am not skilled at regular expression. If I was, Id try my best to figure it out myself.

Comment: Do you have to worry about unclosed apostrophes?  I assume you mean "str 'between this' str"

Comment: No I do not have to worry about unclosed apostrophes

Comment: Regular expressions are extremely powerful - and straightforward ones are easy to write. Now would be a good time to start learning, attempt to write one that accomplishes your needs, and post your attempt here if you are having trouble so we can help you. This is not a "do this for me" kind of site.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a CSV row structure. Could you post a before and after example of a typical string you wish to change?

Comment: It is a csv row structure. Here is a typical string:"1111 SW 2nd Street
Plantation, FL 33324" and I need it to be: "1111 SW 2nd Street Plantation FL 33324". I receive the csv data as one row and i explode on comma, so i need to figure out how to change within that one row the commas and newlines to spaces when they are within apostrophes from parsing just that one row.

Comment: CSV is a nontrivial format. Why not use a CSV parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be applied on all *(exploded)* variables and it will replace `newlines` and `commas` ONLY IF there's a double quote in the variable:

```
$field=preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\,)+(?=.*")/gms',' ',$field);
```

Explained demo with quotes example: http://regex101.com/r/bU2oX5 *(will replace)*

Explained demo without quotes example: http://regex101.com/r/iQ8yY9 *(will not replace)*

**Option 2**

Check if there are double quotes in the variable first:

```
if (strpos($field,'"')!==FALSE) $field=preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|,)+/g',' ',$field);
```